# How do I save a certain row in my database to a new Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, database, pandas

I have located a specific row in my database using:

```
df.loc[df["Cost per m^3/$"].idxmin()]
```

However I would now like to save this row to a new Excel spreadsheet, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
row = df.loc[df["Cost per m^3/$"].idxmin()]
pd.DataFrame(row).to_excel('NewFile.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following trick:

Data:

```
In [120]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [121]: df
Out[121]:
   a  b  c
0  5  9  4
1  4  5  3
2  8  0  1
3  0  3  9
4  6  6  5
```

This returns a series:

```
In [122]: df.loc[df.a.idxmin()]
Out[122]:
a    0
b    3
c    9
Name: 3, dtype: int32
```

let's use list of indexes instead of a scalar value:

```
In [123]: df.loc[[df.a.idxmin()]]
Out[123]:
   a  b  c
3  0  3  9
```

Now you can use `DataFrame.to_excel()` method